# Android audio output to wired headphones and bluetooth at the same time?

Tags: java, android, audio, bluetooth

Before I even attempt to write this android app, I need to know if its possible to do the following with the standard Android SDK library or any known 3rd party library.

Output audio from multiple simultaneuosly playing files to both the wired headphone jack AND bluetooth A2DP at the same time.

Each file/output combination will have its own volume control in the app as well. So if the volume on file 1 is turned down on the headphones but not the bluetooth volume, it still can be heard on a bluetooth speaker but not in the headphones. Same would apply on file 2,3,4 etc

Comment: Did you get any luck with this?